# Determining if the user falls within a zone bounded by two coordinates Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

Lets say that I have two sets of coordinates that bound the island of Bermuda:

```
x1y1 = [32.43059334605672,-64.90143284218118]
x2y2 = [32.233325799581394,-64.62190953125031]
```

And I have a Firebase database with the following structure:

```
"countries": {
    "bermuda": {
        "location": {
            "x1": 32.43059334605672,
            "x2": 32.233325799581394,
            "y1": -64.90143284218118,
            "y2": -64.62190953125031
        }
    }
}
```

After obtaining the users location via GPS of their device (x, y), how would I structure a Firebase query to determine if the user is in Bermuda using javascript? An incomplete snippet is provided below:

```
const getUserLocation = function(latitude, longitude){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var db = firebase.database().ref("countries"); //WHAT NEXT?
        db.on('value', function(response){
            resolve(response.val());
        });        
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property.

There is no way to query the database for both latitude and longitude with your current data structure. This means that you could potentially filter one of your latitude or longitude values in the query, but have to do the others in the client-side code. E.g.

```
    var db = firebase.database().ref("countries");
    db.orderByChild("x1").startAt(x_coordinage).on('value', function(response){
        // TODO: loop over response.forEach and filter out for y1, x2, and y2
    });
```

But as you can probably imagine, this means you're loading a lot of data that you won't need.

There is an add-on library called [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire), which encodes a pair of latitude+longitude values into a magical single value called a [Geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash). With that you can query for items in ranges around a central point. That's still not exactly what you want, but since GeoFire is open-source you may be able to modify it to fit your exact needs.